# Trigger loading animation on each trigger of ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Is it possible to trigger a load event when an ng-repeat re-renders. I can get it working on the initial loading but when loading a new range I can't get the load to trigger again.

**Right now, I have this directive:**

```
.directive('onLastRepeat', function() {
        return function(scope) {
            if (scope.$last){
              setTimeout(function(){
                  scope.$emit('onRepeatLast');
              }, 1);
            }
        };
    })
```

It triggers the first time but not when I change the range of ng-repeat.

**Controller**

```
$scope.$on('onRepeatLast', function(scope){
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.doneLoading = true;
        });
      });
```

**HTML**

```
<md-progress-circular class="loading" ng-hide="doneLoading"></md-progress-circular>

<li ng-repeat="task in done" on-last-repeat>
        {{task}}
      </li>

//I removed extra code to hopefully be more clear, basically I am just querying for a different time range through a service to get the new time range. 

var doneRef = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com.startAt(start).endAt(end);
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Is there a reason for the setTimeout? Also i'm assuming you are actually registering the event somewhere ($scope.$on) correct?

Comment: The original solution had the setTimeout. Here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-catch-ng-repeat-update-angularjs-related/15811/3 I think it has something to do with how $digest works – without the timeout it never triggers. Yes, I do register the event. I'll add that in.

Comment: if you are getting items for `ng-repeat` from server. you can show loading till then. not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: I'm using firebase to load the items. I'm not sure what you mean exactly or how to do that. Sorry.

Comment: setTimeout forces the javascript to the end of execution queue (allows rendering threads etc to catch up).

Comment: How are you reloading the array?  I just tested out what you have and it works...

Comment: I have a service setup to handle loading new items. The array is on $scope and a function runs to change the query range. $scope.done = Tasks.populateTodayTasks($scope.prevDayStart, $scope.prevDayEnd, 'todo', team);

Comment: You may need to use `$scope.$apply();` after you update `$scope.done`. this jsFiddle does what you are trying to do I assume (on a simpler scale). https://jsfiddle.net/honerlawd/9eh44bk7/

Comment: If I add in $scope.$apply() I get an error that a digest is already in progress. I don't think that's it.